# windows 7 service pack 1 and all applicable updates are required to install Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, windows

While I am trying to install Python 3.6.1 it is showing Setup failed.. windows 7 service pack 1 and all applicable updates are required to install Python 3.6.1. 
I am using windows 7 professional OS. 
Waiting for a solution !!

Comment: this not a coding question and there are no error logs or anything to help you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with windows 7 sp1 python 3.5.2 got successfully installed. Pls also chk if windows visual c++ 2015 redistributable is properly installed..

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this type of error is showing while installing a certain application 
(like Python) in the windows 7 platform.

For Solution, you have to install service pack 1 to your os. You can also install the service pack for windows manually as described below.

1. Open regedit (By clicking windows+R key, type regedit and then click enter)
2. Go to HKEY-LOCALMACHINE->SYSTEM->Control->Windows.
3. open CSDVersion
4. Set the value as you want(Like 100 for servicepack 1, 200 for servicepack 2)
   and then click 'Ok'.
5. Restart your PC

Now you can install application

Comment: Thanks so much! we are looking for this for weeks.

Comment: I had to look up for the `CSDVersion` key because it wasn't where you pointed it, the right key name is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Windows`. The instruction works for the 3.6.8 release (but not for 3.8.3), but the installation stops before finish with an "unspecified error" 0x80240017. The installation log says: `Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.` and `Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.` among other messages.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install Python 3.7.5 in Windows 7 service pack 1. It doesn't require windows updates.

Comment: Time and money saving solution (+1)!